# How to add new row to react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I know that this is a very basic question. But I couldn't find the answer by now. In my application, I will fetch some data as an array from my graphql server and directly render it using react-table. now I want to add a new row to this table. How should I do that?  Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

- You should update your `data` object passed to `useTable` (refetch data from `graphql` server, triggering a `useEffect` which fetches data or ...).
- If it is not some data coming from server, you can manually add it to `data` (append).

I think you should always keep the reference to the `data` object.